# Is there a way to track the Simplify process?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Is there any way to track how *Mathematica* actually performs `Simplify`, so that we can see what those "Automatic" transformation functions it applies are and how it works with assumptions?

For example,

```
ClearSystemCache[];
Simplify[Sin[x]^2 + Cos[x]^2, ComplexityFunction -> ((Print[#]; LeafCount[#]) &)]
```

will output

```
Cos[x]^2+Sin[x]^2    
Cos[x]^2+Sin[x]^2    
Cos[x]^2+Sin[x]^2    
Cos[x]^2+Sin[x]^2    
Cos[x]^2+Sin[x]^2    
1    
1    
1
```

Is there a way to see what *Mathematica* does between these steps?

Comment: @Nasser: Is there a way to filter it?  I tried `TableForm[
 Trace[Simplify[Sqrt[x^2], x \[Element] Integers], 
  TraceInternal -> True]]`, and it output far too much output to read ...

Comment: @NoonSilk. `Trace` takes a second argument that allows filtering. See this [documentation[(http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Trace.html) entry

Comment: Sorry, I should've worded my point better - even filtering won't help the problem I observed with the example I posted. Note that the problem is that one entry in the table is exceedingly long.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Nasser stated in his comment,

```
TableForm[Trace[Simplify[Sqrt[x^2], x ∈ Integers], TraceInternal -> True]]
```

will provide you the information you seek. Most of the very long output you encountered comes from *Mathematica* loading packages needed to carry out the simplification. If you evaluate

```
TableForm[Trace[Simplify[Sqrt[x^2], x ∈ Integers], TraceInternal -> True]]
```

a second time, the packages will be already loaded -- the output will still be messy but the `Trace` results will print in their entirety.

Comment: thanks for the answer and the editing. Could you give some hint about how to interpret the trace result? And do you know some resources that discuss how MMA do the simplification? For example, from the trace result, I can see that it uses some numerical functions, but how does it sample the numerical parameter space and how it is sure the sample is large enough?

Comment: @user6048. Sorry, I don't have the expertise to answer you new questions. They are good questions, but they shouldn't be asked in a comment. I suggest you post some new questions to get the answers.